# Most elegant way to query XML string using XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm wondering what the most elegant way is in C# to query a STRING that is valid xml using XPath?

Currently, I am doing this (using LINQ):

```
var el = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
var h2 = el.XPathSelectElement("//h2");
```

Comment: or i suppose using LinqToXML is good too...

Comment: currently, I'm doing this (using linq):

 var el = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
 var h2= el.XPathSelectElement("//h2");

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simple example using Linq to XML :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(someStringContainingXml);
var cats = from node in doc.Descendants("Animal")
           where node.Attribute("Species").Value == "Cat"
           select node.Attribute("Name").Value;
```

Much clearer than XPath IMHO...

Comment: may be cleaner than XPath but does not answer the question.

Comment: @DavidAlpert, perhaps, but it was accepted nevertheless... Anyway, the question is completely subjective: how do you define "elegant"?

Comment: The original question hinges on how you define "elegant... using XPath"

Comment: Elegance inevitably involves brevity and inevitably avoids complexity.

Comment: Your way also uses more processing power, involves more reading. Other way is cleaner and less CPU.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record, I did not want to go with Linq2XML but XPath and found this way:

```
var xPathDoc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader("your XML string goes here"));
```